# Downloadhelper fails to Convert

Tags: firefox, downloads, convert, avconv

I'm trying to use the Firefox Add-On Downloadhelper to download and convert this 'video' of Einstein: http://sploid.gizmodo.com/listening-to-this-incredible-recording-of-einstein-will-1464557213 in order to have only its audio. Unfortunately the conversion fails and I have the following information from the console.

Notes: I opend firefox with sudo

> Executing /usr/bin/avconv -i /tmp/gizmodo_2249.mp4 -y -v 0 -strict experimental -ab 192k -f mp3 /home/jk/dwhelper/gizmodo_2249.mp3

The result was a 0 kB mp3-file.

Update:

I've decided to sudo-open firefox and remove VideoDownloadhelper. Then I opened Firefox as a nomal user with the terminal and installed the Add-On...Problem persists...Now I'm learning to use avconv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to apply "brutal apt-force" and installed the following packages:

> libavcodec53, libavcodec-dev, libavcodec-extra-53, libav-tools, libavformat53, libavformat-extra-53, & libavformat-dev.

and the conversion worked! :)

Comment: ...but downloads from grooveshark still fail.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the file (downloaded it) and it's videotrack is corrupt....that may be the reason that on-the-fy transcoding didn't work out for you.

Downloding the file is no problem. The only thing you have to do is convert it after you downloaded it.  Open the terminal, go to the directory where you downloaded the file and invoke:

```
ffmpeg -i gizmodo_2249.mp4 -vn -acodec copy einstein.aac
```

And almost immediately you'll have exactly what you want: only audio in aac without transcoding so no quality loss.

Comment: hmm...could you tell me what -vn menas? :P I'm still ignorant on that.

Comment: `-vn` means "no video" or more accurately "drop the video stream"

Comment: Thanks, would you vote up my question? :)

Comment: Sure, no problem....can you mark my answer as the chosen answer ? ;-)

Comment: Your answer is still not the correct one, it didn't fix the conversion capability of my download helper :/

Comment: No, the answer is the correct one...a corrupt video can't be converted. There is nothing wrong with the conversion capability of your downloadhelper :-)

Comment: False, it also fails to convert files from grooveshark and youtube...do you know where the commands of Downloadherler are to configure them? ..hhmmm...i think i have an answer but i can't answer my own question in the next 12hours because of my low reputation -_- ...

Comment: well, put your answer in your question, that will do :-)

Comment: I'm allowed to do it in 11hours...see you then!